# Only then are you free?

Tags: grammar, word-order, inversion

Quote from an awesome TED talk ([The prison of your mind](https://youtu.be/VaRO5-V1uK0?t=594) given by [Sean Stephenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Stephenson)):

> When you love yourself, whether you're sleeping on a prison cot, or in a mansion, whether you have food in your belly, or you don't know when your next meal is coming, when you love yourself, when you learn to master your emotions, then and **only then are you free**.

What's the grammar behind "only then are you free"? Because normally we would say "only then you are free", right?

Answer (score 19):

*Only* is one of a set of generally [negative polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) items which, if first in a clause, trigger inversion. (They don't have to stand first, but if they do, inversion is obligatory).

Other examples are *never*, *rarely*, *scarcely*, *neither*, *little*.

*Only* triggers inversion when it is a conjunction followed by a phrase or clause, expressing a limitation on the main clause. When  it has its simple adverbial meaning of "nothing except", it does not usually stand first in the clause, and does not trigger inversion.

If it introduces a clause, that clause does not show inversion.

Examples:

> Never **have I** seen such a thing.

> Little **did I** think that this would be the last time I would see him.

but

> Only in China **can these** be found.

> Only when I got there **did I** see what had happened.
> (The main clause is inverted, but not the clause introduced by *only*.)

> I only wanted to see it. (adverbial *only*, no inversion)

*Few* triggers inversion when it stands alone, as a predicate:

> Few **were the** people who witnessed the event.

but not when it is a determiner:

> A few people witnessed the event. (no inversion).

This construction is most used in literary English, but it is also found in everyday speech.

Comment: I feel this answer would benefit from a more explicit statement that the OP's idea of "only then you are free" is **also perfectly grammatical** in modern English.

Comment: @Max:  _Only then you are free_ is dubious to my ears.

Answer (score 8):

Not quite right - we would say **then you are free**, but **only then** is one of those expressions which require the subject and verb to be inverted. See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/34681).

> I read the letter, and only then did I understand...

Another one is **not until.**

> Not until I read the letter did I understand...

Comment: I don't agree that inversion is required, at least with "only then." Not inverting  seems much too common in speech that otherwise follows normal grammar rules. With "not until," the inversion seems much more strongly required, as the inversion happens after a clause.